# Exception handling and error response to an api

Tags: java, api, exception, httpresponse

I am working to design the exception handling and error responses to an api.
Can anyone let me know how the exceptions designed for enterprise applications.
Can we map java pre defined exceptions to application exceptions. If so, how we have to map the pre defined java exceptions to our application scenario ? if not, how we need to designed the exceptions for enterprise applications ? any guidelines ?
Once the exceptions are mapped it has been to given to service layer. Should error messages(for api response) framed in the service layer ? if yes, can you specify any reason ? if not can you specify any other options for framing error response of any api ? 
Can suggest any design technique followed in your application ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

So all you need to do is write Global Exception Handler by using @ControllerAdvice or @RestControllerAdvice and then write exception handlers.You can map inbuilt Exceptions to exception handlers.So if these exception gets arised  then exception handler's piece of code will get executed.And we can give customized error message so that client will understand what went wrong.

below is code snippet I have developed to handle rest api exceptions.
So In my code I have handled two exceptions NoSuchElementException and MethodArgumentNotValid exception.

eg in my case
If you search record by id and if that record doesnt exist you will get NoSuchElementException so that client will know record does not exist with that id

and for  MethodArgumentNotValid exception I had added constraints to variables 
eg trying to enter negative id this exception will get arised

@ControllerAdvice

public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{

```
  @ExceptionHandler(NoSuchElementException.class)
 public final ResponseEntity<Object>handleRecordNotFoundException(NoSuchElementException ex,WebRequest request)
{
    return handleExceptionInternal(ex,ErrorResponse.builder()
                       .status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
                       .timestamp(new Date())
                       .detail(ex.getLocalizedMessage())
                       .message("Record not found")
                       .build(),new HttpHeaders(),HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,request);

}   

    @Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,HttpHeaders headers,HttpStatus status,WebRequest request)
{
     List<String> errors=new ArrayList<String>();
     for(ObjectError error:ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors())
    {
            errors.add(error.getObjectName()+":"error.getDefaultMessage());
    }   

    return handleExceptionInternal(ex,ErrorResponse.builder().details(errors).build,headers,HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,request);
   }
```

}